# What's the purpose of those lines in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Here is a part of build.gradle:

```
} else if (!versionCodeOverride) {
  def minSdkVersion = minSdkVersionOverride ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
  // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
  // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
  // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
  if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
    defaultConfig.versionCode += 9
  } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
    defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
  }
}
```

It seems that gradle will change `defaultConfig.versionCode` if `versionCodeOverride` has not been set. I search google and don't find some useful information, I think the versionCode is only a number used for Android installing app, does it have other function?

Comment: I had the same question as it seems to be doing some suffixing of the versionCode for other purposes? would be nice to have some documentation on that?